# How do you pay your debts to your parents?

Tags: parents, ayah, debt

I heard that praying and asking Allah is the best way besides trying your best to give parents what they deserve.
They sacrificed everything they had for my future. I miss them a lot.
What are some good ayahs or practices I should follow to repay my parents debts?

Comment: What debts are you talking about? You may never be able to pay back their sacrifice as ibn Omar said to the young man who was carrying his mother on his back and performing hajj with her: she sacrificed everthing for you hoping will grow and survive while you do the same hoping she would die. Nevertheless you could be a good son who performs du'a for them.

Comment: How do I perform dual to satisfy my heart?

Comment: Debts I'm talking about is everything your parents do for you like earning money

Answer (score 1):

Recite as many ayahs as possible. Read surah yaseen and ayatul kursi.

Comment: Do you have any evidence supporting your claims. Or do you guys like cross-voting low quality posts?

Answer (score 0):

Parents have a very high and valuable place in our lives and we should never neglect to respect them. They give birth to a child and give him a life and a family, they become parents who devote all their time and energy to their child and may sometimes forget their interests and desires, and whatever decision they make will surely be for a better future. And it is full of success for their child. When their child is young, parents give all their attention and love to him / her and give him / her peace, security and support, and they certainly ask their child not to forget them in old age. They have sacrificed their lives for our lives, whatever we do for them, we have not repaid a thousandth of their love...

Ref: https://www.javanonline.ir/fa/news/896341/